# Are there any WinForms control libraries which support Mono?

Tags: winforms, mono, grid, controls, libraries

We're migrating an existing WinForms application to Mono so that we can run on Linux and iOS, and we're updating the UI in the process.

I've been looking around at WinForms control libraries to hasten the development, and so far they all seem to say they don't support Mono. Are there any out there (commercial or free) which do support Mono?

Key features we're looking for are a flexible data grid with cell merging and docking/tabbing windows management.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far, this is the biggest product I know migrated from Windows/.NET to Mono,

http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2011/11/07/real-world-feedback-on-a-net-to-mono-migration/

You might learn from this attempt.

Most .NET controls heavily depend on Windows native APIs, so if you plan to migrate to Mono you lose them.

With recent efforts, DockPanel Suite has been upgraded to support Mono (though drag and drop must be sacrificed), which is the only docking/tabbing WinForms control that supports Mono,

http://dockpanelsuite.com

I don't know what can be your option for data grid.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView in GTK# is very flexible, so depending on your needs (and requirements to look and feel) it might be an option to switch to GTK# for the UI instead.

Here is some links:

- [GTK# TreeView tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp_TreeView_Tutorial)
- [GTK# Beginners Guide](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide)
- [GTK# Hello World](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp%3a_Hello_World)

Comment: We've looked at GTK# but we have plugins based on WinForms Control which we have to still support, so to move to GTK# we need to find out how to wrap that...which seems to be a problem...  I'll report our progress in a blog post.